# Behavior of thread by extending Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

I have following `class‍` :

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("I am the first thread");
  }

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Thread1 t = new Thread1();
    t.start();  
    }
}
```

If I run the above program it will print in new thread

```
"I am the first thread"
```

Now in the main if I try to start the same thread twice it will throw `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException`

Now I will rewrite the Thread1 class as below by overriding the `start()` method

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("I am the first thread");
  }

  @Override
  public void start() {
    System.out.println("I am the Start");
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Thread1 t = new Thread1();
    t.start();  
    t.start();  
    }
  }
```

Now if I call `start()` method twice the output will be :

```
  I am in start
  I am in start
```

The above program is throwing any exception. Can anyone explain me this behavior. Why it is not starting the new thread. Seems be to simple but not able understand it.

Comment: What do you think `Thread`'s implementation of `start` does? If you override it, what do you expect should happen? Why do you think so?

Comment: Read the documentation:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--

Comment: try calling `super.start()` in your overridden method and see what happens.

Comment: The default implementation of the start method in class Thread checks if you are starting it for the first time, if yes it calls a native method to start a new thread of execution, calling its run method. If you extend the Thread class and override the start method without calling super.start(), a new thread of execution won't be created.

Comment: @DoubleDouble. Thanks It cleared my doubt. Just to conclude. If the start() method is overridden then by simply calling t.start() will not initiate the new thread, instead it will run as normal overridden method. Suppose we need to want to use our overridden start method to start the thread, then we need to handle it by calling super.start(). Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Any method you override, you change it's functionality which is the whole point of overriding. If you still want the thread to start, you will need to call the implementation which does this. i.e. super.start();

Answer (score 1):

When `@Override`ing a method, your new method that you are creating is what is going to be called *instead* of the previous method.

In class `Thread`, `start()` is a method which does some stuff and starts the Thread.

In your new class `Thread1`, `start()` is a method which just prints out a line and *does nothing else*

---

Your understanding is correct - that calling `super.start()` is calling the superclass's version of `start()` which is allowing the Thread to actually start running.

Note though, that you are still going to be hitting that exception when trying to run it twice. This is the way `Thread` is designed.

From link in comment on question:

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.